# Is the golden hammer fallacy a real fallacy?

Tags: fallacies

Bo Bennet calls the golden hammer a *pseudo*-logical fallacy and describes it thus:

> Proposing the same type of solution to different types of problems. This is more of an error in creativity or knowledge than reasoning.

RationalWiki views it as a logical fallacy and claims it

> occurs when you propose the same, simple solution (or type of solution) to every problem.

Although I can see Bennett's perspective. It does seem more like an error in creativity or knowledge, but the way I see it being used seems deceptive. For example, we have computers, why should anything think that all of reality can be explained as a computer simulation? Or, in a political context, assuming we have funds, does that mean spending money is the appropriate solution to a political problem?

What I am looking for are references that will help me clarify what the golden hammer means in an argument. Is it a fallacy or not? Perhaps it is part of a larger form of reasoning that may or may not be fallacious.  Hence the question:

*Is the golden hammer fallacy a real fallacy?*

---

Bennett, B. "Pseudo-Logical Fallacies" Retrieved on April 28, 2019 from *Logically Fallacious* at https://www.logicallyfallacious.com/tools/lp/Bo/LogicalFallacies/6/Pseudo-Logical-Fallacies

"Golden hammer" Retrieved on April 28, 2019 from *RationalWiki* at https://rationalwiki.org/wiki/Golden_hammer

Comment: The way I see it is that fallacy and *fail* are etymologically very closely related and from similar roots. Both words have meanings to convey error, mistaken judgment, and to deceive, to cheat, or to trick. So imho anything that leads to serious error is somehow fallacious. https://www.etymonline.com/word/fallacy#etymonline_v_1097 https://www.etymonline.com/word/fail

Comment: @Bread I agree. A fallacy may be more than a failure of reasoning. It is often found in the failing of an argument. Deception suggests ethics although it may be people deceiving themselves.

Comment: The more traditional name for this kind of simplistic thinking is "panacea", and "X is not a panacea" is a widely used idiom. It is obviously based on false analogies and hasty generalizations, but also bad judgments and cognitive biases. But in line with calling all kinds of mistakes "fallacies" people talk about "panacea fallacy" as well. I do not think there is such a thing as "real fallacy" when it comes to informal fallacies. Outside of formal reasoning it is impossible to disentangle mistakes in judgment (soundness) from mistakes in reasoning (validity), even *ad baculum*  is a "fallacy"

Comment: Yeah. Sometimes in engineering this is referred to as the X-Y problem.

Comment: @Richard That is the first I've heard the term X-Y Problem: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem  Thank you!

Comment: @FrankHubeny very common problem in engineering generally, and particular in software engineering. 'Solutionising' before deciding if there's actually a problem at all.

Comment: @Richard I can remember as a developer jumping the gun on problems that did not need to be solved. It is good to have management to keep one in line.

Answer (score 6):

**Strictly speaking, this is an abuse of the term "fallacy,"** since the *golden hammer* is not actually an argument, but rather a strategy.  The implied argument under the strategy is either "this worked for X, therefore it will work for Y" (where "Y" does NOT have relevant characteristics in common with "X"), which is a form of a fallacy called "false analogy," or it is "this worked for X, therefore it works for everything," which is called "hasty generalization."